# Len() does not return correct value from SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

When executing the query below, the len() function does not return the correct value

```
id = "123"

# connecting to database
# initializing cursor

cursor.execute(" select id from table where id = '"+id+"' ")

print(list(cursor), "LIST")

for index1 in cursor:
    print(index1)

print(len(list(cursor)), "LENGTH")

if len(list(cursor)) != 1:
    print("not one id")
```

The output is as follows:

```
[(12345,)] LIST
0 LENGTH
not one id
```

The query should return one entry, but the len() function is returning a zero. Why is this?

Comment: Because you ran `for index1 in cursor:` which iterates through a generator - they can only be iterated once and then they are exhausted.

Comment: Use `data = cursor.fetchall()` and then iterate through that

Comment: @roganjosh, just a small correction - they consumed `cursor` on this line `print(list(cursor), "LIST")`. Then it's empty and nothing is printed in the loop, then len is 0, etc.

Comment: Yep, noticed that afterwards @buran. You are correct.

Comment: So, referring to the cursor at all before actually using it will consume the query it executed?

Comment: _Iterating_ through it will, not just simply referring to it. Try `print(list('abc'))` and you'll see that `list()` expands it out (by iterating through the characters). In the case of your `print()` you iterated it and then just threw the result of that away (other than printing to `stdout`)

Comment: @AngoMango Iterating through it will consume the results. You can convert the cursor to a list and then iterate over the list repeatedly.

Comment: @Barmar Am I not converting the cursor to a list by doing list(cursor)? Then printing it should iterate and print the list, not the cursor.

Comment: You need to assign that list to a variable, then iterate over it.

Comment: No, because you (as I said) just printed the result of that. You didn't assign it to a name so you "threw it away". That's exactly why I suggested you use `data = cursor.fetchall()` and you can iterate `data` as many times as you want

Comment: I feel like I shouldn't be using the list as at all until I use the len() function. I agree with @roganjosh that fetchall() should be the solution. But, @Barmar, by converting the cursor to a list and iterating over it, do you mean ```list1 = list(cursor)```, then iterating over list1? That would still exhaust the cursor. Were you referring to something else?

Comment: Barmar was referring to the same thing as me. Only by assignment e.g. `some_name = cursor.fetchall()` or `some_name = list(cursor)` do you get permanence. I'd use the former because it's idiomatic.

Comment: Makes sense. To be clear, converting the cursor to a list and assigning it will exhaust the cursor, but the variable assigned to it should contain the permanent values for iteration.

Comment: Separately, please look into parameterized queries. `cursor.execute(" select id from table where id = '"+id+"' ")` is bugging. me. It should either be `cursor.execute(" select id from table where id =  ?", (id,))` or `cursor.execute(" select id from table where id = %s ", (id,))` depending on the dialect. Look into Bobby Tables and SQL Injection

Comment: @AngoMango correct :)